# Copy in optput of mathematica to clipboard

Tags: copy, wolfram-mathematica

I have a mathematica output which I want to copy to clipboard:

[image]

While pasting this as string on notepad I get the following:

```
\!\(
TagBox[
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "x", ",", "1", ",", "0"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "x", ",", "1", ",", "x"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{"5", ",", "x", ",", "1", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{"5", ",", "x"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"List", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "2"}], ",", "x", ",", "1", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "2"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", "Pi"}], "]"}], 
        ",", "x", ",", "1", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Power", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Plus", "[", 
RowBox[{"16", ",", 
RowBox[{"Times", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Power", "[", 
RowBox[{"E", ",", "2"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Rational", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ",", "2"}], "]"}]}], "]"}], ",", "Pi", ",", "x"}],
          "]"}]}], "]"}]}], "]"}],
ShowSpecialCharacters->False,
ShowStringCharacters->True,
NumberMarks->True],
FullForm]\)
```

How to paste the code as raw string without `Rowbox` and other irrelevant strings?

Comment: right click the right side bar of the cell and there is a menu option "convert to input form" (something like that). Then you can copy normally.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works.

Comment: note by the way, none of the "copy as" options work very well. You need to use the "convert to:input form" , "copy" , then "undo" to put it back to formatted form if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematica function

```
CopyToClipboard[1+x]
```

will put 1+x into your clipboard and not include any of the RowBox.

Comment: `CopyToClipboard` works for simple outputs. But for outputs of `FullForm[expression]`. It gives `RowBox`es

Comment: @Arihant Parsoya Well then do not use FullForm. Without FullForm it should paste the code to your clipboard as you requested. Or perhaps edit your question to more precisely define exactly what you really need to do. Or perhaps InputForm instead of FullForm will paste what you need. Many new users get themselves into trouble in several ways by thinking they need to use some of the *Form that are provided by Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

By right clicking on right side of the cell, we can copy the output in the form required.